# Page flip effect using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to learn about the page flip effect like this one 
http://www.20thingsilearned.com/en-US

Is there any solution already developed in jQuery for this or are there any tutorials regarding this effect? The main thing that I want is that the page flip effect should be compatible with older browsers also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Check out turn.js

http://www.turnjs.com/

Comment: nice one thanks for this but is it compatible with non-html5 supported browsers

Comment: they provide a fallback method for IE < 9

Comment: Please let me know how can I use fallback for IE < 9.

Answer (score 0):

If you want page turning in pre-HTML5 browsers, you will need to use Flash.  Reason being that page turning requires taking an image and gradually distorting it which is simply not possible in pre-HTML5 javascript.  Here's an example of a Flash product which can do this.

http://flippingbook.com/flippingbook-html-edition.htm

Comment: This is a flash version. If you don't mind you can check this [flip book wordpress plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/flip-book-wordpress-plugin/full_screen_preview/152641?ref=revaxarts) out

Answer (score 0):

WowBook is also a nice plugin, works on IE7 and Android 2.2.

http://codecanyon.net/item/wowbook-create-ebooks-with-page-flip/1791563